# What files to put on Bitbucket so that my teams could use?

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, project-management, laravel-5.1

I have a setup a Laravel 5 project locally and want to put it on bitbucket account so that my remote team mates can install it. Locally from command line I ran following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist
```

which did everything. Now it sounds stupid to put all. I already uploaded my `composer.json` file. What instructions should I send out to team so that they just clone directory and install it? Do I dump each thing and they just clone it? Will they have to run `composer create-project` command anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, no need to run `composer create-project`, they just clone the project and run `composer install` to deploy the project in their local.

As `composer install` will install all of the framework's dependencies, don't upload vendor folder to source (Bitbucket).

You can send following instructions

**Project requirments**

List of tools and technologies to run the project

Ex: PHP and mysql version, Frameworks (js, css) used and tools required NodeJs, Gulp, Bower or any other

**Installation process**

1. create folder project_name and clone project into it
2. open composer.phar and run `composer install`
3. setting up environment to run project with required tools

Comment: Ok I did as you suggested, it just created `vendor` folder. No such folder like `app,bootstrap,config,database,public,resources etc` have been created.

Comment: yes, `composer install` or `composer update` will create the vendor folder and Laravel dependencies. did you push all other folders and files to Bitbucket except the vendor folder as I suggest?

Comment: That was the mistake I did earlier. I pushed all stuff other than `vendor`. It worked then!! Thanks a ton!